# emacs smart-tab with yasnippets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs, lisp, yasnippet

I'm trying to get tab complete within all open buffers and yasnippet to both work with the tab key. At the moment I can have one or the other. The following code is how I'm handling the yasnippet expand, but as I'm not a lisp programmer I cannot see the mistake here.

If it cannot expand the snippet I would like it to try and expand from the buffer.

```
;; Auto complete settings / tab settings
;; http://emacsblog.org/2007/03/12/tab-completion-everywhere/ <-- in the comments
(global-set-key [(tab)] 'smart-tab)
(defun smart-tab ()
  "This smart tab is minibuffer compliant: it acts as usual in
    the minibuffer. Else, if mark is active, indents region. Else if
    point is at the end of a symbol, expands it. Else indents the
    current line."
  (interactive)
  (if (minibufferp)
      (unless (minibuffer-complete)
        (dabbrev-expand nil))
    (if mark-active
        (indent-region (region-beginning)
                       (region-end))
      (if (looking-at "\\_>")
          (unless (yas/expand)
            (dabbrev-expand nil))
        (indent-for-tab-command)))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I try to understand what the code does, and what you would like it does.

Your code

- `first checks` if the point is in `the minibuffer`.

  - If so, then it tries to complete the minibuffer

    - if (in minibuffer) cannot complete it, it calls dabbrev-expand
- else if the point is `not in minibuffer`

  - if some region is marked , it indents the region.
  - if `no mark is active`, it checks to see if the point is at the `end of some word`

    - if so, it checks is yasnippet can expand.

      - if yas cannot expand, it calls dabbrev-expand
    - if not, it tries to indent the current line

This is what your code does.

Your code fails due to yas/expand. This command does not return in case the expansion fails.

In case that this command fails, it checks the state of the variable `yas/fallback-behavior`.  If this variable has the value `call-other-command`, as in your case, the failed yas expansion calls the command bound to the key kept in the variable `yas/trigger-key`.

In your case , this variable is `TAB`.

So: You are at the end of the word, You press TAB to complete it, this triggers the interactive `smart-tab`, which calls yas/expand which in case it fails to expand calls the bound function of `TAB`, and here is the infinite loop.

The Solution for your problem is to temporaily bound `nil to yas/fallback-behavior` in this `smart-tab` function.

Here is how to fix it:

```
(if (looking-at "\\_>")
      (let ((yas/fallback-behavior nil))
        (unless (yas/expand)
          (dabbrev-expand nil)))
    (indent-for-tab-command))
```

Comment: Currently if it fails to expand with yasnippet then I get the error 'Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size' and it doesn't expand using dabbrev-expand